# Instagram API - 'URL signature expired' - video thumbnails

Tags: c#, instagram, instagram-api

I am using the [https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token={accessToken} Instagram API endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self) to retrieve the latest posts of images/videos.

Everything works fine except that I am getting a 403 with the message: 'URL signature expired' for video thumbnails, normal images works fine.

Any way to fix this?

I checked permission settings on the API account but it does not look like anything was missing there for video thumbnail permission.

Comment: When do you get the error? Is it when the most recent item is a video, or they are all videos, or when the list contains a video, or..?

Comment: @stuartd any video url that i get from the response, usually its a mix of images and videos in the recent section.

So between OK images i get FORBIDDEN videos